# Non-expiring access token for seeing group pages?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am building a small website and I want to display the latest posts from a private facebook group and link back to them to drive engagement on the facebook group. The server is grabbing the data. I'm not requiring users to sign into the site or anything.

I tested this out on a new private page and got an access token. Everything worked great until the token expired after two hours. I used https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer to generate the token.

What I need is a set and forget token. How can I do that? I saw that there were long lived tokens (like 60 days). My dilemma is that I am not the admin of the private page that the new website will point to. For the long lived token, that particular user would have to sign back into the website and I would have to have some janky javascript to manage it all (taking the right short lived token to promote it to a long lived token).

There has to be a way I can just get an API key (like every other service out there) that does not expire and use that to access the graph api, but I can't find anything with Google and the Facebook API docs are not friendly to newcomers.

Please help :)

Comment: No there is no way to create a non expiring user access token

Comment: ok, so no non-expiring user access token. Is there another way?

Comment: No groups can only be fetched using user access tokens